# Messed up gcc/build-essential - how to revert?

Tags: gcc, build

I have some strange problems regarding my build setup... acutally I am trying to compile

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf( "Hello World!\n" );

  return 0;
}
```

By running

```
gcc -o simple simple.c
```

But this gives some errors. First about cc1 not being found, after adding the path to `$PATH` I now get the error:

```
/usr/include/stdio.h:34:21: fatal error: stddef.h: No such file or directory
```

Long text, short question: How to delete all related stuff and reconfigure everything?
I tried:

```
apt-get purge build-essential && apt-get install build-essential gcc g++
```

but this does not help/work!

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

`build-essential` is a meta package, so I'm not surprised that purging it has no effect.

Some options for rebuilding:

1. `apt-get install --reinstall gcc g++` Not guaranteed to succeed--if this doesn't help, try option 2
2. `apt-get purge gcc g++ && apt-get install gcc g++` This should succeed, but will likely take a large number of development packages with it. You can backup installed packages with the [dpkg --get-selections trick](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-get-list-installed-software-reinstallation-restore.html)
3. (Nuclear option) Backup your installed package list with `dpkg --get-selections` and reinstall Ubuntu

Good luck!